# Horizontal scroll in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, mousewheel

I have this SVG element with a scroll bar. I want to make it horizontally scrollable on mouse wheel. 
[image: scrollable svg]

I use the `(wheel)` event to trigger the method `move()`

```
<div id="tab-primary-wrapper" class="inner-wrapper" (wheel)="move()" #scrollable style="overflow: auto" >
   <div>
```

which does this:

```
 move(){
    var el = document.querySelector('#tab-primary-wrapper .inner-wrapper')
    if(el){
     el.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e: WheelEvent) {
       this.scrollLeft += e.deltaX;
       e.preventDefault();
     });
    }
  }
```

I'm not getting any movement of the scrollbar!

Is there any method which I can use that triggers the movement automatically?

Or, should I implement the scrolling using css?

I would very much appreciate any suggestion, of how would the best way be to proceed further.

**Update:**

In the .html I added an `id="container"` which I accessed in the .ts file:

```
<div id="container" #scrollable style="overflow-x: scroll" (wheel)="onWheel($event)">
    <div>
```

In the typescript I defined:

```
onWheel(event: WheelEvent): void {
    console.log("move...");
      document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 40;
  }
```

where I move from left to right but I cannot move then from right to left.

Answer (score 2):

With `(wheel)` inside the `div`, you declare a `wheel` event handler, there's no need to explicitly add another listener using `addEventListener`.

```
<div ... (wheel)="onWheel($event)" ... ><div>

onWheel(event: WheelEvent): void {
   (<Element>event.target).parentElement.scrollLeft += event.deltaY;
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

Please have a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmfua2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: thank you for your input. Unfortunately the horizontal scrolling doesn't work yet and I get this strange error: `_co.onWheel is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent]`

Comment: **Update:** I got an error because I called the `move()` method instead of the `onWheel()` so that I just renamed. 
Now I don't get any error but just the scrollbar doesn't move on mouse event.

Comment: Try to use event.deltaY

Comment: It doesn't work with deltaY. I wonder if the `.parentElement.scrollLeft` since I use the `(wheel)=onWheel($event)` method on the parent, on the element where the scroll is defined. When we say `parentElement.scrollLeft` doesn't this scroll the parentElement of the current element where the method is defined?

Comment: I did this too, but It unfortunately doesn't move the scroll horizontally...I don't know if trying to do this with css would be a good idea!?

Comment: I updated my answer with a StackBlitz that illustrates how it should work.

Answer (score 2):

To scroll on both ways...

```
  onWheel(event: WheelEvent): void {
    if (event.deltaY > 0) document.getElementById('container')!.scrollLeft += 40;
    else document.getElementById('container')!.scrollLeft -= 40;
  }
```